# Array that contains points of polygon. Can we iterate through it's border?

Tags: arrays, pseudocode

Let's say we have an array filled with points(x,y)(tile), all in pseudocode, that form a closed and filled 2d polygon. How can we iterate only through the points that form the polygon's border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the [gift-wrapping algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm) also known as the Jarvis march, which will output only those points that form the border.

```
jarvis(S)

    // S is the set of points
    pointOnHull = leftmost point in S // which is guaranteed to be part of the CH(S)

   i = 0
   repeat
      P[i] = pointOnHull
      endpoint = S[0]      // initial endpoint for a candidate edge on the hull
      for j from 1 to |S|
         if (endpoint == pointOnHull) or (S[j] is on left of line from P[i] to endpoint)
            endpoint = S[j]   // found greater left turn, update endpoint
      i = i+1
      pointOnHull = endpoint
   until endpoint == P[0]      // wrapped around to first hull point
```

[image]

Comment: will this algorithm work if the polygon is a group of merged rectangles? meaning there will only be 90deg angles

Comment: Of course it will. I don't see any reason (from the pseudo-code) why that would be an issue.

Comment: Ok I'll try that. P[] is a new array that we create inside the loop correct?

Comment: p[ ] does not need to be an array. I think a List might actually be a better choice. As you said it is the final list of points that belongs to the outer edge of the cloud of points.

Comment: And what if there are multiple leftmost points? will that break this algorithm?

Comment: What do you think would happen? Please try reasoning about the code. Or even better, implement and test it. It's a small fragment.